# How to repeat summarise a column based on multiple other column groupby s

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, apply, summary

Let's say I want to calculate the mean (or a custom function) on column A based on different values in columns B-D. Here is the data:

```
input:
data <- data.frame(A = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 10),0),
                   B = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0),
                   C = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0),
                   D = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0))

output (note your rand numbers might result in different summary table):
col value mean    
B   0     5.92
B   1     4.71
C   0     6   
C   1     5.17
D   0     4.89
D   1     6
```

I can do it for each column separately:

```
data %>% group_by(B) %>% summarise(mean(A))
```

I put it in a `for loop`:

```
p <- data.frame(NULL)
for(i in c('B','C','D')){
  q <- data %>% group_by_(i) %>% summarise(col=i,mean = mean(A))
  p <- append(p,q)
}
```

but it didnt work quite as expected. Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to `gather` the data into 'long' format, grouped by 'key', 'val' columns, get the `mean` of 'A'

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(data, key, val, B:D) %>%
     group_by(key, val) %>%
     summarise(A = mean(A))
```

---

Or in `base R`, by `unlist`ing the columnss from 'B' to 'D' and using the grouping column as 'A' with the replicated column names

```
aggregate(A ~ ., cbind(data['A'], cN = names(data)[-1][col(data[-1])], 
           group = unlist(data[-1])), mean)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
data <- data.frame(A = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 10),0),
               B = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0),
               C = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0),
               D = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, using base and the reshape package, would be:

```
data <- data.frame(A = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 10),0),
                   B = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0),
                   C = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0),
                   D = round(runif(20,min = 0,max = 1),0))

melt(t(apply(data[,-1],2,function(x) by(data[,1],x,mean))))

  Var1 Var2    value
1    B    0 4.100000
2    C    0 3.727273
3    D    0 4.250000
4    B    1 4.800000
5    C    1 5.333333
6    D    1 4.583333
```

melt and t functions are just to get the output in the shape you desired